# How to validate input using external javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Im doing app based on phonegap. Im trying t validate my input with external javascript file. But getting error validateForm is not defined at HTMLFormElement.onclick. What's wrong with my code?

HTML

```
<div data-role="page" id="page1">

    <div data-role="header">
        <a href="#pageMain" class="ui-btn ui-icon-back">Back</a>
        <h2>Add New</h2>
    </div>
    <!-- main -->
    <div data-role="main" class="ui-content">

        <form name="myform" onclick="return validateForm()" method="post">
        Name : <input type="text" name="myname" id="my_name" placeholder="Enter Your Name" >
        <button type="button" id="but_submit">Submit</button>
        </form>


    </div>
    <!-- footer -->
    <div data-role="footer">
        <h2>mine</h2>
    </div>

</div>
```

Code from external javascript

```
function validateForm(){
var x = document.forms["myform"]["myname"].value;
if (x==null || x==""){
    alert("enter name");
    return false;
} else{
    return true;
}
}
```

Comment: Where in the document are you loading your script?

Comment: Where did you import the external file, at the top or at the bottom? (EDIT: The comment above this one was posted within 9 seconds of mine)

Comment: Use `onsubmit`, not `onclick`

Comment: at bottom...just before </body>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `onsubmit`, and by passing *`this`* from the event handler, you can use it instead for `document.forms[....]`

HTML

```
<form name="myform" onsubmit="return validateForm(this)" method="post">
```

Script

```
function validateForm(theform){
    var x = theform["myname"].value;
    if (x==null || x==""){
        alert("enter name");
        return false;
    } else{
        return true;
    }
}
```

---

And by using event listeners it can be even more maintainable (and unobtrusive)

HTML

```
<form name="myform" method="post">
```

Script

```
window.addEventListener('load', function() {  /* fires when page been loaded */

    document.querySelector('[name="myform"]').addEventListener('submit', function(e) {
        var x = e.target["myname"].value;
        if (x==null || x==""){
            alert("enter name");
            return false;
        } else{
            return true;
        }
    });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use the `onchange` event because `onclick` triggers before having a chance to actually write something in the input.
This way you can deal with the validation after the value has changed and not wait for the form to be submitted.

Or if you want to validate just before submit you can use the `onsubmit` event like LGSon suggested.

```js
function validateForm() {
  var x = document.forms["myform"]["myname"].value;
  if (x == null || x == "") {
    alert("enter name");
    return false;
  } else {
    console.log(true, x);
    return true;
  }
}
```

```html
<form name="myform" onchange="return validateForm()" method="post">
  Name : <input type="text" name="myname" id="my_name" placeholder="Enter Your Name">
  <button type="button" id="but_submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use below html code:

```
<form name="myform" onsubmit="return validateForm()" method="post">
        Name : <input type="text" name="myname" id="my_name" placeholder="Enter Your Name" >
        <button type="button" id="but_submit">Submit</button>
        </form>
```